sphinx.ext.autodoc: ModuleNotFoundError for external packages
I want to start documenting my flask-based application with Sphinx. Currently, I am trying to figure how to use the autodoc extension. My local modules are all found, but the imports of external libraries does not work in sphinx.
I have all my requirements in a requirements.txt file, so I hope that sphinx could extract the packages/modules form there. I am testing the sphinx on my local machine in an env. Therefore I already added:
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('~/envs'))

to myproject/docs/source/config.py. Which worked for my project-internal modules but not further.
So, running sphinx-build -M html docs/source/ docs/build/ causes this error:
WARNING: Failed to import myproject.errors.
Possible hints:
* ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
* KeyError: 'myproject'
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
writing output... 
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 1 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] api
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'errors' from module 'myproject'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'flask' [autodoc.import_object]

As an mwe I created myproject/docs/source/api.rst:
API
===

.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated

.. automodule:: myproject.errors
    :members:
    :imported-members:

To double-check, whether all of the dependencies are installed, I ran `
(envs) user@machine:~/git/myproject$ pip freeze | grep -F "Flask"
Flask==2.3.3

To exclude any problems, that could be flask-specific, I tried to mock it via autodoc_mock_imports=['flask'] but this shifts the problem to all other external modules one by one.

Are all dependencies in requirements.txt actually installed in the virtual environment?

Thanks @mzjn for your comments! I try to answer all of them by editing my original post

If ~/envs is your virtual environment, then I wonder why you have sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('~/envs')) in conf.py. That looks odd. If you run Sphinx in the virtual environment with all dependencies installed, it should just work. There should be no need to update sys.path.

This was I thought too. Removing sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('~/envs')) does  not change any functionality. But without sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../')) autodoc does not even find all my internal modules: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'errors' from module 'myproject'; the following exception was raised: No module named 'myproject' [autodoc.import_object]

I am not questioning sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../')). That one is required as far as I can tell.

Alright, could it be that I need Intersphinx (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/intersphinx.html) to get it working?

No, I don't think Intersphinx will help. Are you really running sphinx-build inside the virtual environment?

Thank you very much, mzjn! Your hints were correct. I was curiously running all python commands in the venv but the sphinx-build. I proofed this assumptions by adding
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../../'))
print('Sphinx runs with the following prefix:'+sys.prefix)

to my conf.py, which I got from wpercy and I will leave these lines there, for later debugging. After knowing this I tried to do it as migonzalvar describes it:
With the environment activated:
$ source /home/migonzalvar/envs/myenvironment/bin/activate
$ pip install sphinx
$ which sphinx-build
/home/migonzalvar/envs/myenvironment/bin/sphinx-build

Which still did not work. Only after I deactivated the venv and uninstalled sphinx globally via pip uninstall sphinx, sphinx-build started to use the venv (as I intended).
